# sql query how to get who knows morethan two lanuguage

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

My table look like as

```
Id Name Gener    Lan1      Lan2    lan3
------------------------------------------
1  xyz   M       Null      c       c#
2  lmn   M       c#        java    jquery
```

Here how can i write query who knows morethan 2 lanuguage

Comment: why minus? may i knw

Comment: Add some more sample data and also the expected result. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: I suppose downvoters find too little effort made.

Comment: Why you dont create tables for `Languages` and `UserLanagues`(which user knows which languages)? You always want to create a new column when a user learns a language?

Comment: Learn about many-to-many relationships

Comment: simple aggregation will solve your issue. (try `group by` clause)

Comment: Poor base architecture! You should have two tables : one for user and one for the language known by user. users : [uid/name]; language:[uid/language_name].  This way, you should be able to join your two table -> More easy, readable, and beautifull!

Comment: @ThomasGrockowiak Wrong. OP needs 3 Tables: user, language and userLanguage

Comment: Tag your database system (mysql or ms-sql ...) ?

Comment: @Jens Effectively, more readable and effective than my solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help you.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ID,NAME,GENRE,COUNT(LAN1)+COUNT(LAN2)+COUNT(LAN3) AS 
KNOWN_LANG FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY NAME) WHERE KNOWN_LANG >=2
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your DB Design is very poor at all change it as if possible, else you could use `apply` operator to get the user which has more than language.

```
SELECT a.id 
FROM table t
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES (id, Name, Lan1),
           (id, Name, Lan2),
           (id, Name, Lan3)
)a(id, name, lans)
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING COUNT(a.lans) > 1
```

Use `DISTINCT` if one user has same language input in (*Lan1*, *Lan2*, *Lan3*,..)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, if the person doesn't know the language, It has `null` in corresponding column. So, if you want to get people, who know three languages, it's enough to check if all columns are `not null`.

```
select id, name, gender, lan1, lan2, lan3 from MY_TABLE
where [lan1] is not null and [lan2] is not null and [lan3] is not null
```